# Trying to run npm install- getting errors

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am following a tutorial on creating an ERC20 and ICO [Dapp University ERC20 and ICO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IqsgSyA8BQ&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgULF-lbxy-is9x_7mTMHFIN)

I am trying to run npm install and getting this error -

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Foxy098\Desktop\Coding\WhiteCryptoICO\node_modules\sha3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.  
npm ERR!   addon.cpp
npm ERR! C:\Users\Foxy098\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\16.15.0\include\node\node.h(63,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'v8.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Foxy098\Desktop\Coding\WhiteCryptoICO\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj]
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\Foxy098\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.2.32516.85) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Foxy098\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\Desktop\\Coding\\WhiteCryptoICO\\node_modules\\sha3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.15.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.15.0',        
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Foxy098\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.15.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\Desktop\\Coding\\WhiteCryptoICO\\node_modules\\sha3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\Desktop\\Coding\\WhiteCryptoICO\\node_modules\\sha3\\build',      
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe       
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Foxy098\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Foxy098\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Foxy098\Desktop\Coding\WhiteCryptoICO\node_modules\sha3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Foxy098\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-26T08_27_58_965Z-debug-0.log
```

I also tried  this : npm install --global windows-build-tools
and I also tried : npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

Still got errors for both.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed packages with two different node version.

Comment: what does that mean? What should I do ?

Comment: Sometimes, it happens when you installed image cropping package like Sharp. It need to be installed globally first, then to be installed in your local project. For instance, you used node v14 to install sharp globally, but you used v16 to install sharp in your project. This type of error will occurs.